# Truncated objects coloring

Tags: combinatorics, symmetry, coloring, polyhedra

I am looking for ways to color a truncated tetrahedron allowing rotations and reflections. I know the ways to color a tetrahedron in a similar way but stumped on this. From wikipedia, both tetrahedron and truncated tetrahedron have same symmetry groups so I think this can help in reaching an answer.

Also, if there are links that discuss the coloring of truncated objects like truncated cube, truncated octahedral and also for cuboctahedron, that would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I think I misunderstood initially. You're looking to count the number of distinct colorings of a truncated tetrahedron, taking symmetries into account?

Comment: @pjs36 Yes and if possible, for other truncated objects too. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Introductory remark.** With this  problem I strongly urge the reader
to verify  this calculation including  by enumeration which can  be an
interesting coding challenge.

Suppose we  start from a tretrahedron with vertices labeled $1,2,3,4.$
Observe  that  the  rotational  symmetries consist  of  the  identity,
rotations  about an  axis connecting  a vertex  to the  center  of the
opposite face and rotations about an axis passing through the midpoint
of two  opposite edges.  These can be  combined with a  reflection. We
thus obtain for the total number of symmetries

$$2\times(1+ 4\times 2 + 3) = 24$$

which means the symmetries of  the tetrahedron are the symmetric group
$S_4$ consisting of all permutations of the four vertices. Now for the
cycle indices of  the action on vertices and faces in  the case of the
truncated tetrahedron  we must decide  on a canonical labeling  of the
vertices and the  faces. For the vertices we label  them with the edge
of the  original tetrahedron that they  are located on  and the vertex
they are closest to.

$$[\{1,2\}, 1], [\{1,2\}, 2], [\{1,3\}, 1], [\{1,3\}, 3],
[\{1,4\}, 1], [\{1,4\}, 4], \\
[\{2,3\}, 2], [\{2,3\}, 3], [\{2,4\}, 2], [\{2,4\}, 4],
[\{3,4\}, 3], [\{3, 4\}, 4].$$

Letting  the permutations  of $S_4$  act  on these  and factoring  the
result into cycles yields the following cycle index:

$$1/24\,{a_{{1}}}^{12}+1/4\,{a_{{1}}}^{2}{a_{{2}}}^{5}
+1/8\,{a_{{2}}}^{6}+1/3\,{a_{{3}}}^{4}+1/4\,{a_{{4}}}^{3}.$$

and for vertex colorings of at most $n$ colors

$$1, 218, 22815, 703760, 10194250, 90775566, 576941778, 
\\ 2863870080, 11769161895, 41669295250,\ldots$$

the closed form being

$$1/24\,{n}^{12}+1/4\,{n}^{7}+1/8\,{n}^{6}+1/3\,{n}^{4}
+1/4\,{n}^{3}$$

which points us  to [OEIS A060530](https://oeis.org/A060530), where we
find it  listed as  edge colorings  of the cube.  This is  because the
rotational  symmetries of the  cube establish  any permutation  of the
four diagonals, an isomorphism with $S_4.$

Coloring faces  is much simpler and  could be done  manually but we
will re-use the  software we already have. For  the canonical labeling
of  the faces  we label the triangular  faces with  the number  of the
vertex that was present before  truncation and the hexagonal ones with
the three  vertices that formed the  source face which  into which the
hexagon is embedded. We thus obtain

$$1,2,3,4 \quad\text{and}\quad
\{1,2,3\},
\{1,2,4\},
\{2,3,4\},
\{1,3,4\}.$$

We get the cycle index

$$1/24\,{a_{{1}}}^{8}+1/4\,{a_{{1}}}^{4}{a_{{2}}}^{2}
+1/3\,{a_{{1}}}^{2}{a_{{3}}}^{2}
+1/8\,{a_{{2}}}^{4}+1/4\,{a_{{4}}}^{2}$$

and the sequence

$$1, 35, 495, 3876, 20475, 82251, 270725, 766480, 
\\ 1929501, 4421275,\ldots$$

the closed form being

$$1/24\,{n}^{8}+1/4\,{n}^{6}+{\frac {11\,{n}^{4}}{24}}
+1/4\,{n}^{2}$$

which is not yet included in the OEIS.

The coefficients on these  cycle indices suggest there is a better
way to compute them starting  from the shared symmetry between the two
problems.  (These are the coefficients of the terms in $Z(S_4).$) This
is left to the reader.

The Maple code for this computation goes as follows.

```
with(combinat);

pet_autom2cycles :=
proc(src, aut)
local numa, numsubs;
local marks, pos, cycs, cpos, clen;

    numsubs := [seq(src[k]=k, k=1..nops(src))];
    numa := subs(numsubs, aut);

    marks := Array([seq(true, pos=1..nops(aut))]);

    cycs := []; pos := 1;

    while pos <= nops(aut) do
        if marks[pos] then
            clen := 0; cpos := pos;

            while marks[cpos] do
                marks[cpos] := false;
                cpos := numa[cpos];
                clen := clen+1;
            od;

            cycs := [op(cycs), clen];
        fi;

        pos := pos+1;
    od;

    return mul(a[cycs[k]], k=1..nops(cycs));
end;

pet_cycleind_t4h_verts :=
proc()
local perm, cind, verts, vperm;
    cind := 0;

    verts :=
    [[{1,2}, 1], [{1,2}, 2],
     [{1,3}, 1], [{1,3}, 3],
     [{1,4}, 1], [{1,4}, 4],
     [{2,3}, 2], [{2,3}, 3],
     [{2,4}, 2], [{2,4}, 4],
     [{3,4}, 3], [{3,4}, 4]];


    for perm in permute(4) do
        vperm :=
        subs([seq(q=perm[q], q=1..4)], verts);

        cind := cind +
        pet_autom2cycles(verts, vperm);
    od;

    cind/24;
end;

pet_cycleind_t4h_faces :=
proc()
local perm, cind, faces, fperm;
    cind := 0;

    faces :=
    [1,2,3,4,
     {1,2,3}, {1,2,4},
     {2,3,4}, {1,3,4}];

    for perm in permute(4) do
        fperm :=
        subs([seq(q=perm[q], q=1..4)], faces);

        cind := cind +
        pet_autom2cycles(faces, fperm);
    od;

    cind/24;
end;

Xverts :=
subs([seq(a[q]=n, q=1..12)], pet_cycleind_t4h_verts());

Xfaces :=
subs([seq(a[q]=n, q=1..8)], pet_cycleind_t4h_faces());
```

With these colorings we assume  that the available colors are the same
no matter the type of the face (triangular or hexagonal).

**Addendum.** Using the very same  method as above we can also compute
the cycle  indices for  the action  on the faces  and vertices  of the
truncated cube (triangular and octagonal). These get more difficult to
handle  manually  as  the   number  of  vertices  increases.  The  key
obervation here is  that the full symmetries of  the cube are realized
by  labeling  the vertices  with  $3$ bits  (from  zero  to seven,  or
equivalently if a  zero label is not desired from  one to eight) where
vertices  are  adjacent  if  they  differ in  exactly  one  bit.   The
symmetries are  then obtained by  combining a permutation of  the bits
with a bit  flip according to eight possible bit  masks. This is quite
straightforward.

We obtain for the vertices the cycle index

$$1/48\,{a_{{1}}}^{24}+1/8\,{a_{{2}}}^{10}{a_{{1}}}^{4}
+{\frac {13\,{a_{{2}}}^{12}}{48}}+1/6\,{a_{{3}}}^{8}
+1/4\,{a_{{4}}}^{6}+1/6\,{a_{{6}}}^{4}$$

and the closed form

$$1/48\,{n}^{24}+1/8\,{n}^{14}+{\frac {13\,{n}^{12}}{48}}
+1/6\,{n}^{8}+1/4\,{n}^{6}+1/6\,{n}^{4}.$$

For the faces we get the cycle index

$$1/48\,{a_{{1}}}^{14}+1/8\,{a_{{1}}}^{6}{a_{{2}}}^{4}
+1/16\,{a_{{2}}}^{5}{a_{{1}}}^{4}+1/16\,{a_{{2}}}^{6}{a_{{1}}}^{2}
\\+{\frac {7\,{a_{{2}}}^{7}}{48}}+1/6\,{a_{{1}}}^{2}{a_{{3}}}^{4}
+1/8\,{a_{{4}}}^{3}{a_{{1}}}^{2}
\\+1/8\,{a_{{4}}}^{3}a_{{2}}+1/6\,{a_{{6}}}^{2}a_{{2}}$$

and the closed form

$$1/48\,{n}^{14}+1/8\,{n}^{10}+1/16\,{n}^{9}+1/16\,{n}^{8}
\\+{\frac {7\,{n}^{7}}{48}}+1/6\,{n}^{6}+1/8\,{n}^{5}
+1/8\,{n}^{4}+1/6\,{n}^{3}.$$

The Maple code for this goes as follows.

```
with(combinat);

pet_autom2cycles :=
proc(src, aut)
local numa, numsubs;
local marks, pos, cycs, cpos, clen;

    numsubs := [seq(src[k]=k, k=1..nops(src))];
    numa := subs(numsubs, aut);

    marks := Array([seq(true, pos=1..nops(aut))]);

    cycs := []; pos := 1;

    while pos <= nops(aut) do
        if marks[pos] then
            clen := 0; cpos := pos;

            while marks[cpos] do
                marks[cpos] := false;
                cpos := numa[cpos];
                clen := clen+1;
            od;

            cycs := [op(cycs), clen];
        fi;

        pos := pos+1;
    od;

    return mul(a[cycs[k]], k=1..nops(cycs));
end;

pet_cube_symact :=
proc(cv, symp, symf)
local bincbverts, bin, f;
    bincbverts :=
    [[0,0,0], [0,0,1], [0,1,0], [0,1,1],
     [1,0,0], [1,0,1], [1,1,0], [1,1,1]];


    bin := bincbverts[cv];
    bin := [seq(bin[symp[q]], q=1..3)];

    for f to 3 do
        if f in symf then
            bin[f] := 1 - bin[f];
        fi;
    od;

    1 + bin[1]*4 + bin[2]*2 + bin[3];
end;


pet_cycleind_tcube_verts :=
proc()
local bincbverts, cbedg, sl,
    perm, flip, cind, verts, vperm;

    cbedg :=
    [{1,2}, {1,3}, {1,5},
     {2,4}, {2,6}, {3,4},
     {3,7}, {4,8}, {5,6},
     {5,7}, {6,8}, {7,8}];

    verts :=
    [seq(seq([edg, v], v in edg),
         edg in cbedg)];

    cind := 0;

    for perm in permute(3) do
        for flip in powerset(3) do
            sl :=
            [seq(q=pet_cube_symact(q, perm, flip),
                 q=1..8)];

            vperm := subs(sl, verts);

            cind := cind +
            pet_autom2cycles(verts, vperm);
        od;
    od;

    cind/48;
end;


pet_cycleind_tcube_faces :=
proc()
local perm, flip, cind, sl, faces, fperm;
    cind := 0;

    faces :=
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,
     {1,2,3,4}, {1,2,5,6},
     {2,4,6,8}, {1,3,5,7},
     {3,4,7,8}, {5,6,7,8}];

    for perm in permute(3) do
        for flip in powerset(3) do
            sl :=
            [seq(q=pet_cube_symact(q, perm, flip),
                 q=1..8)];

            fperm := subs(sl, faces);

            cind := cind +
            pet_autom2cycles(faces, fperm);
        od;
    od;

    cind/48;
end;

Xverts :=
subs([seq(a[q]=n, q=1..24)], pet_cycleind_tcube_verts());

Xfaces :=
subs([seq(a[q]=n, q=1..14)], pet_cycleind_tcube_faces());
```

**Completion  of task.**  We  can also  color  the $36$  edges of  the
truncated  cube. The symmetries  that act  are of  course the  same as
before and  we encode the edges by  a simple scheme --  use the source
edge from the cube for the edges  that appear in the center of an edge
of the cube  and use a pair  of source edges to indicate  an edge that
appeared  due  to  truncation,  with  the common  vertex  having  been
truncated. Observe that  we may well ask whether  a fourty-five degree
rotation  about  an  axis  connecting  two  opposite  octagonal  faces
contributes to the  symmetries. It does not, however,  because it only
fixes  those two faces  and the  triangular as  well as  the remaining
octagonal faces are left without an image. (In fact one can also argue
that this would  attempt to map an  edge of length  one to an  edge of 
length $\sqrt{2}.$)

We get the following cycle index:

$$1/48\,{a_{{1}}}^{36}+1/8\,{a_{{2}}}^{15}{a_{{1}}}^{6}
\\+1/16\,{a_{{1}}}^{4}{a_{{2}}}^{16}
+1/8\,{a_{{2}}}^{17}{a_{{1}}}^{2}+1/12\,{a_{{2}}}^{18}
\\ +1/6\,{a_{{3}}}^{12}+1/4\,{a_{{4}}}^{9}+1/6\,{a_{{6}}}^{6}.$$

The closed form is

$$1/48\,{n}^{36}+1/8\,{n}^{21}+1/16\,{n}^{20}+1/8\,{n}^{19}
\\+1/12\,{n}^{18}+1/6\,{n}^{12}+1/4\,{n}^{9}+1/6\,{n}^{6}.$$

The Maple code was

```
# common routine omitted

pet_cycleind_tcube_edges :=
proc()
local bincbverts, cbedg, sl,
    perm, flip, cind, edges, eperm, e1, e2, f1, f2;

    cbedg :=
    [{1,2}, {1,3}, {1,5},
     {2,4}, {2,6}, {3,4},
     {3,7}, {4,8}, {5,6},
     {5,7}, {6,8}, {7,8}];

    edges := [seq(e, e in cbedg)];

    for e1 to nops(cbedg) do
        for e2 from e1+1 to nops(cbedg) do
            f1 := cbedg[e1]; f2 := cbedg[e2];

            if nops(f1 intersect f2) = 1 then
                edges :=
                [op(edges), {f1, f2}];
            fi;
        od;
    od;

    cind := 0;

    for perm in permute(3) do
        for flip in powerset(3) do
            sl :=
            [seq(q=pet_cube_symact(q, perm, flip),
                 q=1..8)];

            eperm := subs(sl, edges);

            cind := cind +
            pet_autom2cycles(edges, eperm);
        od;
    od;

    cind/48;
end;

Xedges :=
subs([seq(a[q]=n, q=1..36)], pet_cycleind_tcube_edges());
```

Comment: This is very nice though I don't understand much about group theory. Interestingly, the formula for truncated tetrahedron simplifies to $\frac{n^2(n^2+1)(n^2+2)(n^2+3)}{24}$ and for tetrahedron, it is $\frac{n^2(n^2+1)(n^2+2)(n^2+3)}{24}$. But for truncated cube, there isn't any similarity in the formula. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Good observation. Note that the symmetric group produces ${n+3\choose 4}$ face colorings of an ordinary tetrahedron. Now the hexagonal and the triangular faces do not mix and every cycle of some length from $Z(S_4)$ produces two cycles of this length in the truncated tetrahedron, one for the triangles and another for the hexagons. Substituting $n$ into these squares of the original cycles we obtain ${n^2+3\choose 4}.$

Comment: BTW we can think of the truncated tetrahedron as two nested tetrahedra (one each for the triangular faces and the hexagonal ones). These two have the same center. The second one is upside down,

Comment: That is a nice way to look at it! Thank you so much for the work you put in writing this wonderful answer. This was a great learning experience. :)